# How can i reference the keyword THIS in a file in an imported const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I am importing the const **dailyPhysicalActivityOptions** (as you see down here) into one react file. However, when I click on the last Option of the const (is a Select component) (the one that has the onClick event) it throws an error saying "openPalModal of undefined". This is undefined, i understand it, the question is how can I make the THIS from that const in one file, refer to the THIS of the file that is importing it. Thanks

```html
export const dailyPhysicalActivityOptions = [
  <Option value="1.2">Sedentario <span style={{color:'grey', fontStyle:'italic'}}>(trabajo de escritorio, poco o nada de ejercicio)</span></Option>,
  <Option value="1.375">Ligeramente Activo <span style={{color:'grey', fontStyle:'italic'}}>(ejercicio ligero/deportes 1-3 veces por semana)</span></Option>,
  <Option value="1.55">Moderadamente Activo <span style={{color:'grey', fontStyle:'italic'}}>(ejercicio moderado/deportes 3-5 veces por semana)</span></Option>,
  <Option value="1.725">Muy Activo <span style={{color:'grey', fontStyle:'italic'}}>(ejercicio intenso/deportes 6-7 veces por semana)</span></Option>,
  <Option value="1.9">Extremadamente Activo <span style={{color:'grey', fontStyle:'italic'}}>(ejercicio intenso diario, jornada laboral intensa)</span></Option>,
  <Option value="1.9" onClick={()=>this.openPalModal}>Calcular nivel <span style={{color:'grey', fontStyle:'italic'}}></span></Option>
];
```

Comment: A "file that is importing it" has no `this`. Also consider the case that multiple files import this value… No, the correct solution is to either explicitly reference the object that you want (by importing it), or by exporting a function that you can call and pass the object that should be referenced.

Comment: As @Bergi mentioned it is not possible the way you are exporting/importing that array. Another option is to change your const array to contain each static option as a JSON representation (e.g. `{value: '1.2', name: 'Sedentario', description: 'trabajo de escritorio, poco o nada de ejercicio'}`) and then handle the JSX/HTML templating in the Component that is used in. For the last option it might make sense to keep it as a "hard-coded" option in your component.

Comment: Just make your `dailyPhysicalActivityOptions` a React component and pass it an `onCalculClick` prop which will enable the correct component to reference its own `this` (context).

Comment: Rendering JSX outside of the render cycle like this is also a code smell which will likely lead to bugs, like with SSR or missing provider data, etc.